# Is it possible to upload a file whith js plugin without page redirecting?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me any way i can upload image file without refresh the whole page? May be dojo or any JQuery plugin...
I'v tried

```
$.ajax({
         url: "myurl.php",
         data: $("#form").serialize(),
         type:"POST",
         success:function(){
                     alert("uploaded"); 
                 } 
      });
```

and in the form contains this: `<form> <input type="file" name="p_photo"> </form>`

The problem is that jquery ajax doesn't use `enctype="multipart/fom-data"`.

Thanks your respond is highly deserved!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is just one google search away


Comment: This has been answered dozens of times already.  Please use the search box.

Comment: There are two generally approaches that do not rely on plugins. 1) use an iframe containing the form to post (the iframe reloading does not affect the current page) or; 2) (for newer browsers) use the XHR file upload support which *does* support mutlipart data. In both cases I recommend using an existing wrapper/plugin, which are readily available.

Comment: Cool! Nice job bro. Thanks!

Comment: If the below answer works for you, would you consider setting it as the answer?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, perhaps just use the jQuery file upload plugin:

http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Documentation and examples are at the link above.  Here is the description of this plugin from that website, which will do exactly what you want and a lot more:

> File Upload widget with multiple file selection, drag & drop support,
>   progress bars, validation and preview images, audio and video for
>   jQuery. Supports cross-domain, chunked and resumable file uploads and
>   client-side image resizing. Works with any server-side platform (PHP,
>   Python, Ruby on Rails, Java, Node.js, Go etc.) that supports standard
>   HTML form file uploads.

Here's an example implementation using the "Basic" version of this plugin:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" data-url="path/upload.php" multiple>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

This example expects a JSON response from the server for each uploaded file, which you can provide with something like this snippet (in PHP) once the file is on the server:

```
   <?php
         echo json_encode(array(array(
            'name' => $image->filename,
            'type' => $file->getType(),
            'size' => '$file->getSize(),
            'url' => $file->getUrl()
        )));
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks bro, let me take a try!

Comment: Link only answers do not help anyone but this current poster at this current time.  Try to think of the community as a whole next time you post.

Comment: Once again, if you put some actual effort into your response, I'll be happy to reverse my downvote.  Stackoverflow is not about copying and pasting links.

Comment: Yes, much better.  Downvote reversed.  I'll even throw in an upvote since you took the time to improve your answer.